# what is the relationship between inner product and the complex conjugate of the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have no clue what does the yellow highlighted part mean, would anyone gives some[image]  clearer explanation?

Comment: All it says is that $\langle w, z \rangle = \sum w_{i} \bar{z_{i}} = \overline{\sum w_{i} \bar{z_{i}}} = \sum z_{i} \bar{w_{i}} = \langle z, w \rangle$

Comment: @Mattos got it now.